Local Uniform Convergence of the Fourier Series for Globally Irregular, but Locally Smooth Functions
'On the uniform convergence of the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave' is a previous post in which it was answered that the convergence of the Fourier series of the sawtooth wave is pointwise almost everywhere, but "on the other hand the convergence is uniform over any compact set with a positive distance from 2πZ" (points of discontinuity of the sawtooth function).
I'm searching for sources discussing these types of results. In particular, to learn more about the result stating that the Fourier convergence is uniform on the compact interval $I$ in $[0, 2\pi]$, whenever $f$ is smooth ($C^1$) in a neighbourhood of $I$ (while being completely irregular outside of $I$, piecewise continuous or $C^0$, for instance).
I've seen it multiple times, but I couldn't find any materials discussing/proving/giving proof insights about this result. Is it even really true in general ?
